# Set frame CGReact x position in middle like centerXAnchor NSLayoutConstraint programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, frame

I am creating a simple app which set image as circle by calculate with `frame` of image.

Here is I declare image variable:

```
lazy var imageUserDetailProfileView: UIImageView = {

    let imageView = UIImageView()


    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile-icon")
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.50, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    return imageView


}()
```

Here is i made that frame width and height of image became circle

```
imageUserDetailProfileView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX, y: 20,width: 100, height: 100)
imageUserDetailProfileView.layer.cornerRadius = imageUserDetailProfileView.frame.height/2
```

Now i want image should stay in middle of screen like using `NSLayoutConstraint` which has method `centerXAnchor`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
let midX = view.frame.size.width / 2
let midY = view.frame.size.height / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code.
Custom Method For Image Set In Center Of Any View. Just Call Method And Pass Image & View. Customize according to Use. **Swift 4**

```
  func setImageInCenterOfView(image:UIImage,view:UIView) {

    let imageWidth:CGFloat = 100
    let myImageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: (view.frame.size.width/2)-imageWidth/2, y: (view.frame.size.height/2)-imageWidth/2, width: imageWidth, height: imageWidth))
    myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.frame.size.height/2
    myImageView.image = image
    view.addSubview(myImageView)
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
```